# {Binding} not working in ContentTemplate in Custom Control

Tags: uwp, winui-3

I have tried to override the default `Button` as `ButtonWithLoader`. Everything is working fine except a specific case that {Binding} is not working in ContentTemplate.

Please refer to the image attached below

```
    public sealed class ButtonWithLoader : Button
    {
        public ButtonWithLoader()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ButtonWithLoader);
            RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(IsLoadingProperty, UpdateLoadingState);
        }

        #region IsLoading

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsLoadingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IsLoading), typeof(bool), typeof(ButtonWithLoader), new PropertyMetadata(false));

        public bool IsLoading
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsLoadingProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsLoadingProperty, value); }
        }

        public void UpdateLoadingState(DependencyObject sender, DependencyProperty args)
        {
            if (IsLoading)
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Loading", false);
            }
            else
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "NotLoading", false);
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region ContentPadding

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentPaddingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ContentPadding), typeof(Thickness), typeof(ButtonWithLoader), default);

        public Thickness ContentPadding
        {
            get { return (Thickness)GetValue(ContentPaddingProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ContentPaddingProperty, value); }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

```
    <Style TargetType="local:ButtonWithLoader">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackground}" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundSizing" Value="InnerBorderEdge" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForeground}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPadding}" />
        <Setter Property="ContentPadding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3" />
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{ThemeResource ControlCornerRadius}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ButtonWithLoader">
                    <ContentPresenter
                        x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        BackgroundSizing="{TemplateBinding BackgroundSizing}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                        ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                        CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                        MicrosoftUiXaml:AnimatedIcon.State="Normal">

                        <ContentPresenter.Content>
                            <Grid Margin="0,0,-28,0" Padding="{TemplateBinding ContentPadding}">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ButtonContent" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                                    <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                        <CompositeTransform />
                                    </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                </ContentPresenter>
                                <ProgressRing Margin="10,0,0,0" x:Name="ButtonLoading" Grid.Column="1" IsActive="{TemplateBinding IsLoading}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" MinWidth="12" MinHeight="12" Height="18" Width="18">
                                    <ProgressRing.RenderTransform>
                                        <CompositeTransform />
                                    </ProgressRing.RenderTransform>
                                </ProgressRing>
                            </Grid>
                        </ContentPresenter.Content>

                        <ContentPresenter.BackgroundTransition>
                            <BrushTransition Duration="0:0:0.083" />
                        </ContentPresenter.BackgroundTransition>

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>

                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.(MicrosoftUiXaml:AnimatedIcon.State)" Value="PointerOver"/>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.(MicrosoftUiXaml:AnimatedIcon.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <!-- DisabledVisual Should be handled by the control, not the animated icon. -->
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.(MicrosoftUiXaml:AnimatedIcon.State)" Value="Normal"/>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>

                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="LoadingStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Loading">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" Value="False" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonContent">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="-14" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLoading">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="-14" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="NotLoading">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" Value="True" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonContent">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLoading">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>

                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

[image: Output Screen]

[source code](https://workdrive.zohoexternal.com/external/dd0c80799781f0bfe6e1d76082766544b4d1b1ff972e15fea7ae194e4918151a)

[UPDATE-1]

The solution also need to satisfy the case of reusing the DataTemplate as a resource.

[image]

Comment: Can't build a demo with your code. It is better to share the sample.

Comment: @Ax1le Added the source code link. Kindly check this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you are using binding in the TextBlock, the TextBlock can't find the datacontext for itself. So the binding is actually invalid.  You need to explicitly set the binding path and the source for the TextBlock.  So you need to give the `local:ButtonWithLoader` a name and set the path in your code.

Like this:

```
  <local:ButtonWithLoader x:Name="Myloader" Grid.Row="1" Background="Gray" Margin="0,20,0,0" Width="100" Content="Wrapping Text 123">
        <local:ButtonWithLoader.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Content,ElementName=Myloader}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:ButtonWithLoader.ContentTemplate>
    </local:ButtonWithLoader>
```

**Update:**

I checked your custom style and dig it a little bit, I found that you've already defined the `Content` property in the style instead of the `ContentTemplate` property. You added a **ProgressRing** control in it. I think you want to create a button that could show text and the **ProgressRing** at the same time, right?

But the code you are using now is trying to assign another DataTemplate to the `ContentTemplate` property. This will override the content of the Button. The custom grid that you put in the custom style will be covered by the `DataTemplate`. No matter whether the binding work or not, the **ProgressRing** won't show. I guess this is not the behavior that you want to get.

If you just want to set string data for the custom Button, Then you should just use the content property instead of adding another DataTemplate which contains just a TextBlock with binding.

```
  <local:ButtonWithLoader x:Name="Myloader2" Grid.Row="1" IsLoading="True" Background="Gray" Margin="0,20,0,0" Width="100" Content="{Binding text}">
        
    </local:ButtonWithLoader>
```

If you have other requirements for the custom button, you should move the custom part of the ContentPresenter.Content of the style, and put them into the ContentTemplate. Like:

```
  <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" >
            <Grid Margin="0,0,-28,0" Padding="{Binding ContentPadding}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ButtonContent" Content="{Binding Content,RelativeSource= {RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}">
                    <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform />
                    </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                </ContentPresenter>
                <ProgressRing Margin="10,0,0,0" x:Name="ButtonLoading" 
                              Grid.Column="1" 
                              IsActive="{Binding IsLoading}"
                              Foreground="{Binding Foreground}"
                              MinWidth="12" MinHeight="12" Height="18" Width="18">
                    <ProgressRing.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform />
                    </ProgressRing.RenderTransform>
                </ProgressRing>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

  <local:ButtonWithLoader x:Name="Myloader"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Background="Gray"
                            Margin="0,20,0,0"
                            Width="200" 
                            Content="Wrapping Text 123"
                            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}"/>
```

Comment: This solution is working fine. But with this solution, we can't reuse the DataTemplate as a resource as it is using the button name for binding. attached a reference image in the main thread.